# How to add a view to a specifc point on mapView

Tags: java, android, touch, android-mapview

an When an onTouch event occurs on my MapView, i want layout i have specified to be drawn above the where the user has touched

The below is where i have started, i do not know how to actually place the popup view on the x and y values retrieved from the event. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, MapView mapView) {

int X = (int)ev.getX();          
int Y = (int)ev.getY();

ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)map.getParent();
View popup=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.popup, parent, false);

((ViewGroup)map.getParent()).addView(popup);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `MapView.LayoutParams()` with the values of x and y and then call the MapView's `addView` with the LayoutParams.

```
MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y, alignment);
mapView.addView(popup, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, your need one global Point with your X,Y coordinates

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, MapView mapView) {
    int X = (int)ev.getX();          
    int Y = (int)ev.getY();

    selectedPoint = new Point(X,Y);
    return true;
}
```

Now, you should override the onDraw() method to draw you popup view. There are many solutions to do that, I've tried this one with StaticLayout:

```
@Override
public void draw (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, false); 
    if ( selectedPoint != null) {

        // here you should define PopupText, textPaint and width variables

        StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(popupText, textPaint, width, 
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);  

        // here you can draw a rectangle — border for your popup text. 
        // You can use sl.getWidth() and sl.getWidth() methods to get the popup dimensions  

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(selectedPoint.x, selectedPoint.y);
        sl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore()
    }
}
```